# GitlabCI run pipeline on specific branch and manual

Tags: gitlab-ci

So i am unable to specify this two things togather

build/deploy with these specific conditions.

From a specific branchb : develop
And allow to run any branch from web **run pipeline** button.

Ive tried adding both conditions but this builds non develop branches

```
my_build:
  stage: build
  only: 
    - develop
    - web
```

If i remove **web** it works only on develop branch but im  not allowed to run the job from web button

Has anyone achieved this before ?

Comment: The question statement is not that much clear. Do you want to run your pipeline manually via web interface for a particular branch?

Comment: I want to be able to run pipeline manually for any branch. And one specific branch (develop) automatically. (Sorry if i wasnt clearer)

Comment: Then Answer provided by@Thomas is the solution.

Comment: @RuwankaMadhushan it didnt work for me, but i get to do something useful from his answers. Thanks all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I understand: You want to run the builds on branch `develop` automatically but in branch `web` manually?

You can't do this in one build, but you can use two builds for it:

```
my_build:develop
  stage: build
  only:
    - develop

my_build:web
  stage: build
  only:
    - web
  when: manual
```

Comment: does ''when: manual'' exists ? 
this is sort of an answer, but i can work with this.
There is no  web branch, web was the keyword (iirc) that allows manual run of the pipeline (from the web)

Comment: Invalid YAML.  Do you mean `my_build_develop:` and `my_build_web:` rather than `my_build:develop` ?

Comment: Yes, you're right. You also can put the names into quotes.

Answer (score 25):

You can do this with the [`rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules-clauses) clause, [introduced](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/27863) in GitLab 12.3:

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
```

`$CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` is what you have set as the default branch in your GitLab repository settings.

See this [example repo](https://gitlab.com/brendan-demo/default-or-manual-deploy) that a member of the GitLab team created.

Comment: Can this simplified by omiting `if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` and just use `- when: manual`?

Answer (score 0):

use [CI RUN] in your commmit message.
Ex: git commit -m "fixed merge conflicts [CI RUN]"

Comment: Not scalable when we want to force some code quality checks. People will skip it